# socket_recv packet missing bytes PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to receive a packet on PHP, but looks like socket_recv lose some bytes.

I know the packet was sended ok:

```
0:13:58.951742 IP 192.168.0.101.1458 > 192.168.0.107.8000: Flags [P.], seq 1:7, ack 1, win 64240, length 6
    0x0000:  4500 002e 631d 4000 8006 158c c0a8 0065  E...c.@........e
    0x0010:  c0a8 006b 05b2 1f40 6557 d628 4e87 cadd  ...k...@eW.(N...
    0x0020:  5018 faf0 e808 0000 0068 6f6c 6100       P........hola.
```

and the data sended is: 0000 0068 6f6c 6100

but whit:

```
socket_recv($socket, $buffer, 100, 0);
echo bin2hex($buffer); 
echo unpack("H*", $buffer);
```

im getting on both echo's: 00686f6c6100

that means:

```
sended:  0000 0068 6f6c 6100
receive:   00   68 6f6c 6100
```

what im doing wrong?

thanks.

edit: I found the problem. Was on the code.
thanks!

Comment: How are you sending the info? Looks like it's converting to numeric so zeros are removed.

Comment: im sending the info with a C++ socket in another machine.
I dont think there is an error there, because the captured packed is from where PHP is listen, that means the packet arrive ok and complete.

Comment: mind sharing wrong and fixed code?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> echo sprintf( "%02x", unpack("H*", $buffer));

You may have to break the bytes into two parts first though. IE Im not sure if 0x0000 is being translated as 0x0 to 0 (twice) or 0x0000 to 00.

Comment: well, it's almost the same, i understand your point but what happen on the second byte?.
whit your theory should be:
sended:  0000 0068 6f6c 6100
receive:   00  068 6f6c 6100

so we have another 0 missing.

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.